# Open Source Control Libraries with liberal licences for Winforms, WPF and ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, wpf, winforms, open-source

I am looking for **free "Open Source" controls** (respectivels control **libraries**) for **Winforms**, **WPF** and **ASP.NET** with (very) **liberal licences** (like MIT-, Apache or BSD-Licence; not GPL or LGPL!), which can be used in **commercial projects with proprietary licences**.

Which ones are your suggestions and what would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside **Codeplex** take a look at **Sourceforge**. There are also good controls for MS technologies with liberal licences (e.g. the "Advanced Tree View" Control, which is under BSD Licence: http://sourceforge.net/projects/treeviewadv/). Sometimes there are also good controls on **Codeproject**.

**Devexpress** provides also free controls: https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/
But I am not sure, what the conditions are with this collection

Answer (score 6):

CodePlex.com has a bunch. You'd have to check the licenses of each project you are interested in.